# How I can install module at magento 2.1 from admin area?

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento2

i tried to install payment module at Magento 2.1, i read [this](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-install-extensions-in-magento2) and following step by step, but not success. I apologize if I repeat a question, but nowhere I could find something to help me.

Answer (score 0):

1 . In the root directory of your Magento create folders  app/code/Payment/Mymodule. You can use FileZilla for doing this.

2. Copy all files and folders from your payment module archive app/code/Namespace/Module.
3. And run these commands on your Magento 2 root using CLI:

   ```
   rm -rf var/di var/generation var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/*
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   php bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade
   php bin/magento setup:di:compile
   php bin/magento cache:clean
   php bin/magento cache:flush
   php bin/magento indexer:reindex
   ```
4. First go to Stores --> Configuration and then ADVANCED --> Advanced where you can see your module.